# Difference between the static initializer block and regular static initialization

Tags: java, static, initialization

As the title says, what exactly is the difference between

```
public static String myString = "Hello World!";
```

and

```
public static String myString;

static {
    myString = "Hello World";
}
```

is there any important difference other than the structure ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For your example, there is no difference.  But as you can see,

```
public static String myString = "Hello World!";
```

can only accept an expression to initialize the variable.  However, in a [static initializer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7) (JLS 8.7), any number of statements may be executed.  E.g. it's possible to do this:

```
static
{
    myString = "Hello";
    myString += " ";
    myString += "World";
}
```

For your example, there's obviously no need to do that, but it's possible for the initialization of a variable to take more than an expression, perhaps many statements, so Java made static initializers.

Answer (score 6):

The static {...} block gives you the opportunity to do more than you would be able to do in the field declaration.

For example, you can fill in some details of a map:

```
private static final Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();

static {
    data.put("A", "Hello");
    data.put("B", "There");
    data.put("C", "You");
}
```

Sometimes you may also need to get data (from a file, database, etc) before you can instantiate:

```
public class Foo {
    private static final Person person;

    static {
        InputStream personData = Foo.class.getResourceAsStream("something.txt");
        person = new Person(personData);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Difference between static initializer block and regular static initialization.

In case of variable initialization both are same.

But If we want to connect with database only once or any operation you want to load once. Then write the code in static block because its execute only once when first class load no matter how many objects of that type you create.

**EDIT :**

You can also construct a similar block:

```
{
    // Do Something...
}
```

Example:

```
public class Demo {

    static{
        System.out.println("Static");
    }

    {
        System.out.println("Non-static block");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Demo demo = new Demo();
        Demo demo2 = new Demo();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

Static

Non-static block

Non-static block

Answer (score 2):

Well, in your first example the variable is declared and initialized on the same line. In your second the variable is first declared, then initialized. In the second case you could have any number of other static variable and block initializations occur before getting to the initialization block in question. Consider this case:

```
public static String myString = "Hello World!";
public static String yourString = myString;
static {
    System.out.println(myString);
    System.out.println(yourString);
}
```

vs:

```
public static String myString ;
public static String yourString = myString;

static {
    myString = "Hello World";
}

static {
    System.out.println(myString);
    System.out.println(yourString);
}
```

Output from the first example:

```
Hello World
Hello World
```

Output from the second example:

```
Hello World
null
```

Answer (score 2):

with static blocks you can change the order of the initialisation different to the order of declaration.

Answer (score 2):

To continue with what Scott Stanchfield wrote, you can use the `Collections.unmodifiableXXX()` methods for safety, though libraries like Google Guava may make that less necessary.  Consider:

```
public static final Map<String, String> CAPITALS;
static {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>(); //Java 7.
    map.put("NY", "Albany");
    map.put("MD", "Annapolis");
    map.put("VA", "Richmond");
    map.put("CT", "Hartford");
    // 46 more states
    CAPITALS = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}
```

Of course, having a 52-line static block may be disorienting, and so you might instead take the static block and turn it into a static method.

```
public static final Map<String, String> CAPITALS = capitals();
private static Map<String, String> capitals() {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>(); //Java 7.
    map.put("NY", "Albany");
    map.put("MD", "Annapolis");
    map.put("VA", "Richmond");
    map.put("CT", "Hartford");
    // 46 more states
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}
```

The difference is a matter of style. You might instead just work with a database table.

Answer (score 1):

A static variable stores a value that is shared between all instances (or the non-instance) of the Class it is defined in.

A static block is a section of code that gets executed when Class is first loaded.

"regarding scope, static block is accssible only in the same class"," whereas static variable can be accessed from any class"

Answer (score 1):

Generally a static variable's value is shared between all instances (or the non-instance) of the Class it is defined in where a static block is a section of code that gets executed when Class is first loaded. Functionally There is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

It is really really surprising that the **MOST IMPORTANT** feature is NOT explicitly answered here.

Yes, you can have multiple lines. But what's the point in this? You could also use just one call to a factory method in the in-line static initialization assignment. (`static public final MyType mySPVar = factoryCreateObject();`)

**So let's focus on `static public final` variables:**

But WHAT IF that method (or any of your multiple lines) throws `Exception`s or even `Throwable`s?

- `Checked Exceptions` (not derived from `RuntimeException`)
- or `Unchecked Exceptions` that can be
- - derived from `RuntimeException`
- - or derived from other `Throwable`s, like `Error`

The **most important aspect** of *initializer blocks* (static and non-static) is the ability to do **localized individual Exception Handling** that still grant the **exclusive/privileged access** that other methods cannot provide.

With *exclusive/privileged access* I address the issues of

- being the first code to run inside this *Class* (after the static variable initializers) , so we have a truly pure state
- being the **only** place in code blocks where you can assign final variables (unless you use Reflection, of course)
- not having to take care of *localized synchronization*, because
- - the static  initializer method for each specific class never runs in parallel to itself
- - under normal Java conditions (no *Reflection* or *Bytecode Weaving/Injection* magic; things that the JVM would allow, as opposed to plain-old-Java), each static initializer is guaranteed to only be run once.

And to oppose some of the other answers here: concerning *clean code*, static and publicly accessible fields should be final - if not even immutable. This is where the *initializer blocks* work best.

**Now let's take a look at the other cases:**

For any other scenario like

- (being able to) change the variable later on (not final)
- or letting it only be accessed only through a method (variable not public, together with a *Getter* method)

different solutions are much better:

- For changing a variable later on a *Setter Method* should be used to control the state of the variable/class/object
- for only accessing the variable via a method one could also use lazy initialization, something along the line `if(myObj == null) {myObj = new Something();} return myObj;` (consider *synchronization* here!)

**Addendum:**

All this talk here considers (static) class variables, but most points written here also strongly relate to (non-static) object member variables.