# What is the use of constructor in JAVA when you can initialize the instance variable at the time of it's declaration?

Tags: java, object, constructor, initialization, instance-variables

1st program without constructor:

```
public class Sample1 {
    int a=9;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Sample1 obj = new Sample1();  // I know this is a default constructor
        System.out.println(obj.a);
    }
}
```

Output: 9

2nd program with constructor:

```
public class Sample1 {
    int a;
    Sample1(){
        a=9;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Sample1 obj = new Sample1();
        System.out.println(obj.a);
    }
}
```

Output: 9

If both the things give same output then what's the use of taking the pain to declare constructor?

Comment: That's a great way to do it _if_ your constructor is that simple.  Many aren't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of a no-arg constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48553000/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-no-arg-constructor)

Answer (score 1):

For this usecase, there really isn't much of a difference. Constructors are usually useful in two scenarios:

1. When you want to take arguments instead of initializing the members to hard-coded values.
2. If you have some logic you want to run when the instance is constructed.

Answer (score 1):

This is closely related, although it refers mostly to static:
[Difference between the static initializer block and regular static initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485637/difference-between-the-static-initializer-block-and-regular-static-initializatio/68111887#68111887)

So in a few bullet points:

- Essentially, for you, they're equal
- variables get initialized first, then the CTOR gets run (but be aware, with inheritance some differences may arise)
- in both you can assign final `variables`
- inside the CTOR, you can process parameters given
- initiailizing inside the CTOR has the big advantage that you can handle exceptions
- in variable initialization, you cannot call any method that throws a Checked Exception (derived fom `Exception` but not from `RuntimeException`
- in variable initialization, you cannot control what happens when the variable initialization throws and Unchecked Exception (`Throwable`, `Error`, `RuntimeException`)
- inside the CTOR you can also do CTOR Chaining or reference super class CTORs